# Eclipse android emulator doesn't close when 'x' is pressed

Tags: android, emulation, shutdown

I just reinstalled the new version of Ubuntu, and afterwards eclipse + android sdk and AVD. Now, when I create a new emulator, after it loads, if I *press* the ' **x** ' button, both the emulator and eclipse *freeze*. Even if I close the emulator in task manager, eclipse still tells me that I haven't closed that emulator. I fix the problem by restarting the pc, but that can become frustrating after a while.
Has anyone had this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post configuration of your machine I faced similar thing when working on my 4 year old machine :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet not meet this problem.
What's the version of your eclipse? You'd better use RCP eclipse for android development.
The URL for RCP eclipse:
[eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/heliossr2)

Comment: the pc is new Specs: AMD X4 640 4cores 3.0ghz, 4 GB ram, nVidia GT430 1GB and the eclipse Version is: 3.5.2
Build id: M20100211-1343

Comment: I reinstalled eclipse, but the problem persists; when I want to close the emulator, everything breaks, and I have to restart the pc.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I solved it by installing the 3.6.2(classic version) from the eclipse webpage